# c++ template function pointer

Tags: c++, templates

I encounter a c++ template function poniter problem, please help. thanks so much.

```
class AAA {
  public:
    template<typename K>
    void dooo(K str) {
      std::cout << str << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename Class, typename ret, typename K>
using Func = ret (Class::*) (K);

int main() {
  Func<AAA, void, int> myFunc = &AAA::dooo;

  myFunc(3);

  return 0;
}
```

Complie: clang++ -std=c++11 -o c c.cc

Error:

```
error: called object type 'Func<AAA, void, int>' (aka 'void (AAA::*)(int)') is not a function or function pointer

  myFunc(3);

  ~~~~~~^

1 error generated.
```

Comment: try declaring the function static in the class. Otherwise it's a member function and needs a *this.

Comment: This isn't a template issue; if you replace `K` with `int` everywhere it still happens. The issue is with pointer-to-member; to use one of those, you need an instance of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `dooo()` is not a `static` member function of `AAA` you need an instance of `AAA` to call `myFunc` on:

```
AAA a;
(a.*myFunc)(3);
```

Comment: Oh, yes. It should be a static function, or, I should use 'a' to call the function. Thanks so much.

Comment: "It should be a static function" if so, it should be
`template<typename Class, typename ret, typename K> using Func = ret (*) (K);`

Comment: @Swordfish In that case you shouldn't have `Class` as a template parameter to `Func` at all.

Comment: @Daniel H True that. c&p oversight.